# Polymorphic vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi can someone please explain what is wrong with the following code?I am first including the child of an abstract class in another class which will be using this child.

```
#include "child.h"
```

Then I'm populating the 2d vector below with pointers which point to instances of the child.

```
vector<vector<abstractitem*>*>vec;
```

I am then using this class function in my class. The function get is found in the abstract class.

```
void fn::getall()
{
    for (int i=0;i<m_nrows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m_ncolumns;j++) 
        {   

            vec[i][j]->get(); //error on this line: do you intend to use . instead?

        } 
        printf("\n");
    }  

}
```

Your help  will be much appreciated.

Comment: You've probably meant to write `vector<vector<abstract*>> vec` instead?

Comment: `vec[i]` gives you a `vector<abstract*>*`. `vec[i][j]` gives you a `vector<abstract*>`. If you want to use pointers everywhere, you need to understand how they work.

Comment: Thankyou this solved my problem. Im new with pointers. Can you please explain why vector<abstract*>* gives you vec[i] instead of what i was looking for?

Comment: Because, for `T* t`, the expression `t[N]` gives you a reference to a `T`, `N` places forward from `*t`.

Answer (score 3):

you either need to change

```
vector<vector<abstract*>*> vec;
```

into

```
vector<vector<abstract*>> vec;
```

or change

```
vec[i][j]->get();
```

into

```
(*vec[i])[j]->get();
```

the former is probably better, there is no good reason why the outer vector should hold pointers to the inner vector.

even better would be using smart pointers:

```
vector<vector<shared_ptr<abstract>>> vec;
```

it frees you completely from object memory management

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your outer vector is a vector of *pointers to vectors*, not a vector of *vectors*. This means that your function call resolves like this:

```
vec[i][j]->get();
(vector<abstractitem*>*)[j]->get();
*(vector<abstractitem*>* + j)->get();
vector<abstractitem*> ->get();
```

You can see the error in the last line: your get() function is attempting to run on a vector, but you wrote it expecting it to be an `abstractitem*`.

Either change your declaration to a vector of vectors, or add a dereference to your call:

```
vector<vector<abstractitem*>> vec; //option 1
(*vec[i])[j]->get(); //option 2
```